# Compiler complain about "invalid type argument of ‘->’", why?

Tags: c

I have this function:

```
void simul(char *new)
{

    segment_table seg = malloc(sizeof(st));
    segcode newcode = malloc(sizeof(sc));
    int clen = 0;
    seg -> segname = new;
    clen = code_length(seg -> segname);
    seg -> code = read_hexcode(seg -> segname, newcode, clen);
    load_image(seg, clen-3);
    if (strstr(new, "paper_boot-strap loader.hexcode") == NULL)
            run(segment_offset(seg));
}
```

When I try to compile my program I get the following errors:

```
error: ‘st’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: ‘sc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘segment_table’)
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘segment_table’)
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘segment_table’)
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘segment_table’)
```

- What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you actually *read* the error messages, what do you think they mean? For example, what do you think the message "error: ‘st’ undeclared" means? Why do you think you would get that error?

Comment: Let me guess, probably `‘st’ undeclared`. Or maybe `‘sc’ undeclared`...

Comment: If this is really C++, using new as a variable name is not allowed. If this is C, please use the correct tag.

Comment: This is C.  ‘st’ and 'sc' is undeclared

Comment: Okay, you know what the errors mean, how do you think you could solve them? Where are `st` and `sc` defined?

Comment: Oh, and please update the tags to the correct language.

Comment: How can i declare it please ?

Comment: Lets ask you a *seemingly* unrelated question: What do you think the purpose of header files are? You know the one you use with `#include`?

Comment: typedef st; and  typedef sc;

Comment: the problem is not include because in my function, i put

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

Comment: A header file is where you declare and define things needed by multiple source files. You put the definition of the structures (the *complete* structure) in the header file, together with any type-alias declarations. Then you include the header file in all source files needing those symbols from the header file. You need to put your structures in a header file, and include that header file.

Comment: Can i have an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Header file, for example `header.h`:

```
// First an include guard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
#ifndef HEADER_
#define HEADER_

// Define the structures and their type-aliases
typedef struct st { ... } st;
typedef struct sc { ... } sc;

// Declare a couple of other type-aliases
// (Note that I personally recommend against declaring pointer type-aliases)
// (I personally recommend against using type-aliases for simple types
// like the above structures too)
typedef st *segment_table;
typedef sc *segcode;

// Declare a function prototype
void simul(char *new);

#endif  // HEADER_
```

One source file

```
#include "header.h"

void simul(char *new)
{
    ...
}
```

Second source file

```
#include "header.h"

int main(void)
{
    sumul("some string");
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but for error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘segment_table’) how can i declare it in my  Header file ?